# Apache .htaccess for deny all files in a folder not ending with .min.js?

Tags: javascript, regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm already using (in my `/web/css` folder) the following `.htaccess` file for obscuring source `.less` files (LESS files):

```
<Files  ~ "\.less$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

I can't do something very similar for  JavaScript files in `/web/js`: deny if the file doesn't end in `.min.js`. This maybe due to my little understanding of regular expression, so please go easy with me!

```
<Files  ~ "[^min]\.js$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

A file not ending with `min.js` should be denied, but - actually - seems to allow all.

Comment: What if you allow all `min.js` instead of vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

Try `FilesMatch` like this:

```
<FilesMatch "(?!^.*min\.js$)^.+?\.js$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Alternative solution using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^min\.js$ - [F]
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me (maybe it's Apache settings?). No files are permitted (i.e. app.min.js gives me forbidden error and so app.js).

Comment: Ok try `Alternative solution` in my answer.

Comment: I'm already using a rewrite rule - I don't want to mess with it :)

Comment: Yes don't need to change your rewrite rule, just add mu suggested rule.

Comment: I have also updated regex in `FilesMatch` and that should also work now.